# converting from int to long long

Tags: c++

I tried to convert my programm from int to long long, but the return argument seems to have a problem with that, because XCode says something about an implicit conversion between int and long long..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int potenzieren(long long basis, long long exponent)
{
    long long  ergebnis = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<exponent; i = i+1)
    {
        ergebnis = ergebnis*basis;
    }
    cout << basis << " hoch " << exponent << " = " << ergebnis << "\r";
    return ergebnis;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Programm zum Potenzieren.\r";
    long long a=0;
    long long b=0;
    cout << "Basis?:";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Exponent?: ";
    cin >> b;

    potenzieren(a,b);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `double double`? Surely you mean `long long`, no?

Comment: The return type of your function is int.  Change it to long long.  Or double double.  You may have to cast explicitly.

Comment: Yeah i ment long long.

Comment: But my ergebnis is already set to long long?

Comment: But when you return from the function it is trying to convert it to an int since that is the return type.  Change the return type.

Comment: @Lukas You told your function to return potatoes, so it will surely not return carrots.

Comment: Thanks. Totally oversaw this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change return type of below function to long long. The reason why you get this error is an implicit conversion of return type from long long to int in 'potenzieren' function will return in loss of data.

Also please fix 'i' to be long long (otherwise your for loop may never end if exponent is beyond range of int)

```
long long potenzieren(long long basis, long long exponent)
{
    long long  ergebnis = 1;
    for (long long i=0; i<exponent; i = i+1)
    {
        ergebnis = ergebnis*basis;
    }
    cout << basis << " hoch " << exponent << " = " << ergebnis << "\r";
    return ergebnis;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This function still returns an `int`:

```
int potenzieren(long long basis, long long exponent)
{
    long long  ergebnis = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<exponent; i = i+1)
    {
        ergebnis = ergebnis*basis;
    }
    cout << basis << " hoch " << exponent << " = " << ergebnis << "\r";
    return ergebnis;
}
```

If you want it to return a `long long` you need to change its return type:

```
long long potenzieren(long long basis, long long exponent)
{
    long long  ergebnis = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<exponent; i = i+1)
    {
        ergebnis = ergebnis*basis;
    }
    cout << basis << " hoch " << exponent << " = " << ergebnis << "\r";
    return ergebnis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you really want to return an `int` and you are sure that it will not cause an overflow, you can simply explicitly convert your `long long` to an `int` that way:

```
return static_cast<int>(ergebnis);
```

That way the compiler will know that this is what you want and should not warn you anymore.